# Sending POST data with WWW in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity, php, http

I would like to use Unity's WWW class to send a an HTTP request with POST data. So in my server, my PHP script can do something like

```
$number = $_POST["NUMBER"];
```

According to http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-ctor.html, I can provide a byte array in the constructor to represent such data.

I'm a bit puzzled - suppose I want to send a mapping from "NUMBER" to `200` - how would I create a byte array compatible with my PHP script in Unity C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using the overloaded construct that take a [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) as second parameter, WWW class is automatically considered as an http post request.

Your code can be something like:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField( "NUMBER", aNumber );

WWW postRequest = new WWW( server_url, form );
```